# Python: json.loads() causing '500 internal server error'

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 and cherrypy 3.7, and am running them on Ubuntu 14.04. I cannot install new modules for this project as I am using a university desktop.

After adding this line to a function:

```
    in_dict = json.loads(parameters)
```

Pressing the button in my app that causes this function to be called resulted in a '500 internal server error'.
Parameters is a dictionary-turned-json object.
It's definitely this line that is causing the error.

Here is the error message in full:

500 Internal Server Error

The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/afs/ec.auckland.ac.nz/users/h/r/hril230/unixhome/Documents/hril230/Project/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 670, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/afs/ec.auckland.ac.nz/users/h/r/hril230/unixhome/Documents/hril230/Project/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 217, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/afs/ec.auckland.ac.nz/users/h/r/hril230/unixhome/Documents/hril230/Project/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 61, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "mainFile.py", line 146, in sendMessage
    msgResponse = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

Here are my imports:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cherrypy
import urllib2
import hashlib
import urllib
#import ipgetter TODO:Uncomment before handing in
import socket
import json
```

Here is the function that sends:

```
#This function sends a message TODO: Finish this, delete temp link
@cherrypy.expose
def sendMessage(self, sender, info, message):
    destination = info[:7] #destination obtained
    relevant = info[10:]
    i = 0
    while (relevant[i] != ","):
        i += 1
    ip = relevant[:i] #IP obtained
    portUnfinished = relevant[(i+1):]
    i = 0
    while (portUnfinished[i] != ","):
        i += 1
    port = portUnfinished[:i] #port obtained
    out_dict = {"sender":sender, "destination":destination, "message":message}
    parameters = json.dumps(out_dict) #all parameters are now combined into a json object
    req = urllib2.Request("http://127.0.0.1:8080/receiveMessage", parameters, {'Content-Type':'application/json'})
    msgResponse = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
    return msgResponse
```

Here is the function that receives:

```
#API IMPLEMENTED: /receiveMessage TODO: Complete this function
@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.tools.json_in()
def receiveMessage(self):
    in_dict = json.loads(parameters)
    return "0"
```

Why does the line "in_dict = json.loads(parameters)" cause this error?

Update: It has been brought to my attention by the very useful Eli Rose that parameters shouldn't be the argument for json.loads(). In order to find out what should, I went back to the instructions we were given on using json, and realized I had used the wrong instruction in the wrong place. I should have used:

```
var = cherrypy.request.json
```

Thank you everyone who commented!

Comment: Thank you Cfreak, I hadn't realized I'd messed up the format. :)

Comment: You *are* aware that you can use [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io) to install 3rd-party modules locally, aren't you?

Comment: Oh, no I wasn't, thank you! I'll look into that.

Comment: Tried installing something, pip permission denied

Comment: Is `parameters` a global variable?

Comment: No, it's not. Does it need to be? I thought it got passed through since it was an argument in urllib2.Request. I'll make it global and see if it helps.

Comment: Don't make it global, although I think that's your error  -- `parameters` is not in scope in `receiveMessage`. I don't know `urllib2` (I use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module for this stuff) but I suspect there's some way for `receiveMessage` to access the request it's supposed to be receiving. From what I understand, `parameters` that you receive should be different than `parameters` that you send, no?

Comment: Yes, thank you! You're right I've been doing it wrong. I'll try to find out what the proper argument for json.loads() is.

Comment: Answer: I was using the wrong command all along, I should have used cherrypy.request.json. Very glad that's solved

Comment: How about posting your entire code? Not only a segment

Comment: My entire code is very long and mostly not relevant to this, and the question's been answered anyway, but thanks for the suggestion.